# Submit form with file upload doesn't send submit in the post variable

Tags: php, forms

I have a problem. I'm able to upload some file but not all of them. In phpinfo, the **upload_max_filesize** is set to **64M**. The file bigger than 3Mo doesn't send the $_POST["submit"] (when I do a var_dump)... And I got no error message...

```
var_dump($_POST);

if(ISSET($_POST["submit"])) {
    while($rowSecteur=getRowElement($resultListeSecteur)){
        if (ISSET($_FILES["fileToUpload".$rowSecteur['IDSecteur']])) {
            $target_dir = "uploads/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload".$rowSecteur['IDSecteur']]["name"]);
            $uploadOK = 1;
            $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
            if(!empty($_FILES["fileToUpload".$rowSecteur['IDSecteur']]["tmp_name"])){
                $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload".$rowSecteur['IDSecteur']]["tmp_name"]);
                if($check !== false) {
                    $uploadOK = 1;
                    include 'uploadPlan.php';
                }
                else {
                    $msg = '<div id="msg" class="alert alert-error">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="alert-heading">'._("Error!").'</h4>
                        <p>'. _("The file ' ").$_FILES['fileToUpload'.$rowSecteur['IDSecteur']]['name']._(" ' must be an image or the file size is incorrect.").'</p>
                    </div>';
                    $uploadOK = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

form code :

```
<form id="formMapSecteur" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="selectMap.php">
    <div id="fileBrowser<?php echo $rowSecteur['IDSecteur']?>" class="form-group form-inline col-sm-4">
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload<?php echo $rowSecteur['IDSecteur']?>" id="fileToUpload<?php echo $rowSecteur['IDSecteur']?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-inline col-sm-4 pull-right">
        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo _("Save")?></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Does someone understand what's going wrong in my code?

Here's the result of the var_dump when the file is smaller than 3Mo (exactly 2.85Mo) :
    `array (size=1)`
`'submit' => string '' (length=0)`

and when the file is bigger than 3Mo (3.13Mo):
`array (size=0)`
`empty`

Comment: Form element is missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: I thought it was the problem, I don't know why I didn't put it, habitually, I always put it in the form tag... But I've tried it and nothing has changed...

Comment: Next check is php.ini `post_max_size` value

Comment: Yes!!! It's the first time I heard about this value in php.ini and now it works! Thanks a lot Tristan!

Comment: If you got the answer above, please post it here and accept your own answer rather than keeping the question open. Thanks.

Comment: How can I do it? I can accept my own post...

Comment: Yes, you put the solution in an Answer and then accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post_max_size was set to 3M so I set it to 8M

Thanks to Tristan for the solution.